# Trim/Extend Line using Revit API

Tags: revit-api

How to implement Trim/Extend line command using the Revit API? Currently I'm not able find any API which helps trim line programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `LocationCurve` via the element's `Location` property like this:

```
      // Trim or extend existing pipes
 
      (pipes[0].Location as LocationCurve).Curve
        = Line.CreateBound( p0, q0 );
 
      (pipes[1].Location as LocationCurve).Curve
        = Line.CreateBound( p1, q1 );
```

For a full working sample, please refer to The Building Coder research on [Calculating a Rolling Offset Between Two Pipes](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/01/calculating-a-rolling-offset-between-two-pipes.html).